# CentOS 6.4 with samba - windows workstations fail to mount share when the internet router is down

Tags: centos, samba

A basic Centos6 setup, SElinux and iptables completely off. In a small office network, where the samba share is used to share documents between 10 users and their windows 7 machines.

No AD in place, just samba based users set for all the windows folks. No DNS in the network, all the users have a static mapping to `\\IP\share` of the samba host.

This works fine as long as there is internet access, however, when the router goes down, suddenly none of the users can reach `\\IP\share` - it simply times out.

All IPs are given out by the DHCP server in the router, with very long leases, the centos IP is static. All the stations, including the samba host use the google DNS IPs, however, I don't see why it should matter, when I use naked IPs for smb access, but it seems like this is where things fail when I have no internet in place.

I wonder if anyone has had this issue, and there's some option in smb.conf hidden away, to disable DNS checks or whatever

Thanks

Comment: Two things: 1. When the problem occurs do the affected clients still have valid DHCP assigned ip addresses? Can they ping the server or other hosts? 2. Is the share on the same subnet as the clients?

Comment: 1. yes and yes 2. yes. It's a very basic setup, 24 bit subnet, single gateway, the soho router, a bunch of win7 workstations in a workgroup and the samba server. icmp works, but samba stops as soon as the router goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the logs? log.smbd & log.nmbd ?

You cannot access the shares at all or you have to wait just for timeout?

options in smb.conf
name resolv order
dns proxy

there's also 'netbios name' option
make sure your centos box can resolve its name to IP, /etc/hosts in this case

Comment: I'll start looking into the logs as soon as I have access to the host, so far all I've got is the issue description, unfortunately. The shares cannot be accessed as soon as internet access is gone (router down.) I'll check smb.conf for the options you mentioned, thanks